# overflow: hidden; not working on embeded twitter feed

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have put my twitter feed in the side bar of my page, but the side war is small enough that the scroll bar obstructs the the tweets. I am using overflow: hidden; to try and hide it but that is not working. This is currently what I am working with.

```
.twitter-timeline {
overflow: hidden;
}
<body>
<div id="sidebar"><a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/btwItsTaco" data-widget-id="723159349183414273">Tweets by @btwItsTaco</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></div>
</body
```

Comment: Maybe put it in a `style`-tag?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `data-chrome="noscrollbar"` in your link to remove the unwanted scrollbar because ovverwrite CSS won't work with embedded twitter feed.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5c47rxb/2/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but that didn't seem to work on safari. It worked on  google chrome just fine, but my teacher is grading it using safari. Is there a way to use it in safari as well?

Comment: I've tested it with browserstack on safari 5.1, working good. What is your version / teacher version of safari ?

Comment: The school computers are running 9.0.2 ver safari

Comment: I've tested it on Firefox, Chrome, even IE10. It's weird the Safari issue :/ 
Can you do a screenshot of the JSFiddle running into your Safari version please ?

Comment: That is very odd, it works in the Fiddle just fine, but in my webpage the scroll bar still appears. Link to screenshot: http://imgur.com/hDBjZvR

Comment: Can we have an online access to your webpage ? It's gonna be hard to debug otherwise.